# Por qué no obtengo la suma desagregada para los boletos con promoción?

Tags: c

hola gente tengo un problema con un codigo quiero que ve divida el precio de los que son promocion y me sume el total pero no me lo divide me suma el total de todos sin dividir los que son promocion:
El enunciado es asi:
El sistema de entradas para un Teatro debe considerar el precio basado en la ubicación y en si se
aplica o no promoción (Descuento 30% con Club Teatro). Diseñe la solución que controle la venta
de dichas entradas a fin de saber la cantidad de personas que utilizaron la promoción, la cantidad
total de personas y el monto total recaudado al cerrar el evento.
Los sectores y la cantidad de asientos disponibles son:

1. Sector Vip: $ 550 – Total disponible: 50 asientos.
2. Sector bajo: $ 350 – Total disponible: 55 asientos.
3. Platea: $ 250 – Total disponible: 80 asientos.
   Se solicita implementar un menú para administrar las ventas, finalizando cuando el operador indica
   que no desea registrar más ventas. Antes de finalizar mostrar los totales solicitados

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int menu;
    int ubicacion;
    int total;
    int op;
    int promocionados=0;
    int entradas;
    int sectorvip=0, sectorbajo=0, Platea=0;
    int preciovip=0, preciobajo=0, precioplatea=0;
    
    printf("Bienvenido al menu\n");
    printf("Desea registrar la venta de una entrada?  (1=si 0=no): ");
    scanf("%d", &menu);
    
    while(menu==1){
        printf("1-Sector Vip: $ 550\n");
        printf("2-Sector bajo: $ 350 \n");
        printf("3- Platea: $ 250\n");
        printf("Selecccione un tipo de entrada: ");
        scanf("%d", &entradas);
        switch(entradas){
        case 1:
            printf("seleccionaste sectorvip\n");
            sectorvip++;
            preciovip+= 550;
            printf("Es miembro de Club Teatro? (1=si 0=no)");
            scanf("%d", &entradas);
            if(op==1){
                
                promocionados++;
                preciovip*0.3;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("seleccionaste sector bajo\n");
            sectorbajo++;
            preciobajo+= 350;
            printf("Es miembro de Club Teatro? (1=si 0=no)");
            scanf("%d", &entradas);
            if(op==1){
                
                promocionados++;
                preciobajo*0.3;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("seleccionaste platea\n");
            Platea++;
            precioplatea+= 250;
            printf("Es miembro de Club Teatro? (1=si 0=no)");
            scanf("%d", &entradas);
            if(op==1){
                
                promocionados++;
                precioplatea*0.3;
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("error\n");
        }
            total= preciovip+ preciobajo+ precioplatea;;
            
     printf("Entradas del sector vip vendidas: %d de 50\n", sectorvip);
     printf("Entradas del sector bajo vendidas: %d de 55\n", sectorbajo);
     printf("Entradas de platea vendidas: %d de 80\n", Platea);
     printf("Entradas vendidas con promocion: %d\n", sectorvip);
     printf("Total de ganancias: $%d\n", total);
     
     printf("Desea registrar la venta de otra entrada?  (1=si 0=no): ");
     scanf("%d", &menu);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pon en el título _qué problema tienes_. "Qué estoy haciendo mal" no es nada descriptivo, ni ayudará a que otras personas con un problema similar al tuyo encuentren tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, no olvides colocar el resultado esperado y el obtenido.

Comment: creo que el error es que no pusiste el precio original de la entrada prueba: preciobajo= 350 * 0.3;

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

*Después del asiento seleccionado, tiene que entrar la condición si es miembro del club para que así puedas aplicar el descuento en caso contrario, tomara el valor sin descuento

*Al imprimir el umero de promociones te equivocaste y tienes que agregar la variable promocionados para que así en cualquier asiento elegido por el usuario pueda agregarse la promoción.

te comparto el código corregido ¡Saludos!

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int menu;
int ubicacion;
int total;
int op;
int promocionados=0;
int entradas=0;
int sectorvip=0, sectorbajo=0, Platea=0;
int preciovip=0, preciobajo=0, precioplatea=0;

printf("Bienvenido al menu\n");
printf("Desea registrar la venta de una entrada?  (1=si 0=no): ");
scanf("%d", &menu);

while(menu==1){
    printf("1-Sector Vip: $ 550\n");
    printf("2-Sector bajo: $ 350 \n");
    printf("3- Platea: $ 250\n");
    printf("Selecccione un tipo de entrada: ");
    scanf("%d", &entradas);
    switch(entradas){
    case 1:
        printf("seleccionaste sectorvip\n");
        sectorvip++;
        printf("Es miembro de Club Teatro? (1=si 0=no)");
        scanf("%d", &entradas);
        if(entradas==1){
            
            promocionados++;
            preciovip+=550*0.3;
        }
        else{
        
        preciovip+= 550;
  }
       
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("seleccionaste sector bajo\n");
        sectorbajo++;
        printf("Es miembro de Club Teatro? (1=si 0=no)");
        scanf("%d", &entradas);
        if(entradas==1){
            
            promocionados++;
            preciobajo=350*0.3;
            
        }
        else{
        
        preciobajo+= 350;
    }
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("seleccionaste platea\n");
        Platea++;
          printf("Es miembro de Club Teatro? (1=si 0=no)");
        scanf("%d", &entradas);
        if(entradas==1){
            
            promocionados++;
            precioplatea=250*0.3;
            promocionados++;
        }
        else{
        
        precioplatea+= 250;
  }
        break;
    default:
        printf("error\n");
    }
        total= preciovip+ preciobajo+ precioplatea;;
        
 printf("Entradas del sector vip vendidas: %d de 50\n", sectorvip);
 printf("Entradas del sector bajo vendidas: %d de 55\n", sectorbajo);
 printf("Entradas de platea vendidas: %d de 80\n", Platea);
 printf("Entradas vendidas con promocion: %d\n", promocionados);
 printf("Total de ganancias: $%d\n", total);
 
 printf("Desea registrar la venta de otra entrada?  (1=si 0=no): ");
 scanf("%d", &menu);
}


return 0;
```

}